# Android Install Eclipse project onto DeviceAnywhere

Tags: android, eclipse, project, device, apk

How can I install an Eclipse Android project onto deviceanywhere to test on different devices?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to upload your apk to a webserver somewhere, then browse to it from the device anywhere device, download the apk, and install it. Make sure the device has "install from unknown sources" allowed in the settings.

Comment: AT&T blocks the "install from unknown sources" option. Is there any work-around for testing apps on AT&T devices in DeviceAnywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on [virtual usb](http://deviceanywhere.typepad.com/deviceanywhere/2009/05/connect-your-pc-to-deviceanywhere-devices-with-vusb.html). According to DeviceAnywhere blog you can do that.

And re AT&T - even without unknown sources option you can still install application using usb debugging mode.